# Finite geometry - how to determine parallel classes

Tags: geometry, finite-fields, projective-geometry, finite-geometry

I try to learn a little about finite geometry and I have now encountered the following exercise:

---

**Exercise:**

Construct the affine plane $\mathrm{AP}(\mathbb{Z}_3)$. Determine it's parallel classes and the corresponding Latin squares for the classes of finite nonzero slope.

---

I understand how you construct the lines

(i) slope of 0: $y=0$, $y=1$, $y=2$

(ii) Slope 1: $y=x$, $y=x+1$, $y=x+2$

(ii) Slope 2: $y=2x$, $y=2x+1$, $y=2x+2$

But then, when I look at the solution, they have drawn a pictures but I can't see how they relate to each other and why. The picture looks like this (now drawn in paint ;) )

[image]

Hope someone can explain this to me. I read another example from my text-book but i never understood it then. So i thought, perhaps if I do an exercise I will grasp it. But no luck with that either. I'm not really sure I even understand what a parallell class is. why have they drawn the picture like this? Why do the left-top get the number 3 and so? Would be happy if someone could answer this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These three lines form the parallel class of lines having slope 2.  I think they are shown as kind of weird in this drawing, but it is arbitrary what order they are in.  For example, consider $y = 2x$, this line is satisfied by $(0,0)$, $(1,2)$, $(2,1)$.  These three points make up the blue line in the picture.

None of these three lines intersect, and they partition the points of the plane; that is what makes them a parallel class.